# H-Captcha can't verify captcha key/token

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, hcaptcha

Here is my code:

```
let result = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://hcaptcha.com/siteverify',
            params: {
                secret: "secret would be here",
                response: req.body.hcap
            }
        });
        let data = result.data || {};
        console.log(result)
        if(!data.success){
            res.send("bad token")
            return
        }
        else{
            res.send("good token") 
        }
```

I know that the token sent to the server is good.

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
'error-codes': [ 'missing-input-response', 'missing-input-secret' ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution to be installing the [hcaptcha package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hcaptcha) which made this a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You have to transfer your data to a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) object.
The following code works for me:

```
const res = await axios
    .post(
        "https://hcaptcha.com/siteverify",
        new URLSearchParams({
            secret: process.env.HCAPTCHA_SECRET ?? "",
            response: verificationToken
        })
    )
    .then(res => res.data);
```